# Any purely geometric solution to this problem?

Tags: geometry

[image]

What is the largest possible area of a rectangle(in square units) inscribed in the triangle shown in the picture above?

Comment: @Henry What is this based upon?

Comment: Connect the midpoints of two sides and drop perpendiculars onto the third side.  This is a rectangle with half the area of the triangle.  Affine transformations mean that if this is optimal for any triangle (e.g. an isosceles right-angled triangle) then it is optimal for any triangle.

Comment: To correct my original comment (since deleted), as this triangle has an obtuse angle, there is one possible rectangle, half the area of the triangle.  If all the angles were acute, then there would be three such rectangles.

Comment: @Henry: Affine transformations do not preserve rectangles.

Comment: Christian: that is true, as affine transformations turn rectangles into parallelograms, but these parallelograms have the same areas as rectangles in the transformed triangle with the same base and perpendicular height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\triangle ABC$ be the given triangle with $AB = 10$, $AC = 17$, and $BC = 21$. Choose an arbitrary point $M$ on the side $AB$, and let $x = AM$. Let $N$ be the point on $AC$ such that $MN \parallel  BC$, and points $P$, and $Q$ on $BC$ such that $NP \perp BC$, and $MQ \perp BC$. Thus $MNPQ$ is a rectangle. Let $h_a$ be the length of the altitude from $A$. Note that $h_a$ is constant. The we have the followings proportions:

$\dfrac{BM}{BA} = \dfrac{MQ}{h_a} \to \dfrac{10-x}{10} = \dfrac{MQ}{h_a} \to MQ = \dfrac{h_a}{10}\cdot (10-x)$. Also:

$\dfrac{AM}{AB} = \dfrac{MN}{BC} \to \dfrac{x}{10} = \dfrac{MN}{21} \to MN = \dfrac{21}{10}\cdot x$.

Let $S(x)$ be the area of the rectangle $MNPQ$, then:

$S(x)  = MN\cdot MQ = \dfrac{21h_a}{100}\cdot x(10 - x)$. Since:

$x + (10 - x) = 10$, a constant, $S$ achieves a maximum value when $x = 10 - x$, or $x = 5$.

From this we can solve for $MN =\dfrac{21}{2}$, and $MQ = \dfrac{h_a}{2}$. Thus:

$S_{max} = \dfrac{21h_a}{4} = \dfrac{S_{\triangle ABC}}{2}$

**Note:** $h_a$ can be calculated using Heron formula.

Comment: This is assuming the rectangle that maximize the area has a side parallel to one of the sides of the triangle. This is probably true but I can't see any easy justification of that.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

You can prove that any such rectangle has the area at most half the triangle area via a few simple cases (of course, there always exists such a rectangle):

1. *Two sides parallel.* For any right triangle, and any rectangle with sides parallel to the sides other than hypotenuse: to maximize the area the rectangle has to have proportions of the triangle.
   [image: one]
2. *One side parallel.* Any triangle and any rectangle with at least one side parallel to some side of the triangle: put a line perpendicular to that side which goes through one of the triangle vertices (it doesn't need to be a height) and use the previous point.[image: two]
3. *No sides parallel.* Any triangle and any rectangle: take a line that goes through one of the triangle vertices and is parallel to one of the sides of the rectangle, and use previous point.[image: three]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Beautiful chain of reductions.

Answer (score 5):

Let us generalize the case to obtain the largest rectangle inscribed in any triangle.
[image]

Let $AB=b$ and $CF=h$. Let $x$ and $y$ be the length and wide of rectangle, respectively. It is easy to notice that $\Delta ABC\sim \Delta CDE$. Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{b}&=\frac{h-y}{h}\\
x&=\frac{b(h-y)}{h}.\tag1
\end{align}
The area of rectangle is $xy$ and by substituting equation $(1)$ to $xy$ we will obtain
\begin{align}
xy&=\frac{b(h-y)y}{h}\\
&=\frac{-b(y^2-hy)}{h}\\
&=\frac{-b\left(y-\dfrac12h\right)^2+\dfrac14bh^2}{h}.\tag2
\end{align}
It can be seen from  the equation $(2)$ that the area of rectangle will be maximum when $y=\dfrac12h$, therefore the largest area of rectangle inscribed in any triangle is $\dfrac14bh$ or half of the area of the triangle. Substituting $y=\dfrac12h$ to equation $(1)$ yields
$$
x=\frac{b\left(h-\dfrac12h\right)}{h}=\dfrac12b.
$$
Thus, the maximum area of rectangle occurs when the midpoints of two sides of the triangle were joined to make a side of the rectangle.

---

Now, let $AB=21$, $BC=17$, and $AC=10$. Using cosine formula, we will obtain
$$
\cos A=\frac{10^2+21^2-17^2}{2\cdot10\cdot21}=\frac35\quad\Rightarrow\quad\sin A=\frac45.
$$
The area of $\Delta ABC$ is
$$
[\Delta ABC]=\frac12\cdot AB\cdot BC\cdot\sin A=84\text{ square units.}
$$
Thus, the maximum area of rectangle is
$$
\frac12[\Delta ABC]=\large\color{blue}{42\text{ square units}}.
$$

Comment: Don't you have to consider all threes sides as basis $b$?

Comment: @lhf The area of $\Delta ABC$ will always be the same regardless the base we choose.

Comment: What if the rectangle isn't parallel to any of the sides of the triangle?

Comment: What if $A$ or $B$ is an obtuse angle?

Comment: @dtldarek I built my argument based on the picture I used. If we construct the rectangle isn't parallel to any of the sides of the triangle (esp. obtuse triangle), then the possible max area is $\dfrac12h^2$, where $h$ is the perpendicular distance between obtuse point to the base. In this case, the area of rectangle will be $32$ square units.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen If $A$ or $B$ is an obtuse angle, isn't the argument will be the same as my answer right now?

Comment: I think if the angle next to the chosen "base line" is obtuse, the maximal rectangle standing on that base has an area that is only half the area of the part of the triangle which is above the base. As an example, in the 10-17-21 triangle, what is the maximal rectangle whose side is a part of the triangle side of length 17?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The base of triangle is $17$ then its height is $\dfrac{2\cdot84}{17}$. Thus the maximum area is $\dfrac12\cdot17\cdot\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{2\cdot84}{17}=42$.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: with an obtuse angled triangle, an equivalent rectangle based on an edge of the obtuse angle will not be within the triangle. Shrinking the rectangle to fit will mean it has a smaller area than the rectangle opposite the obtuse angle.

Comment: @Henry Exactly, so if you base the rectangle on a leg of the obtuse angle (a "short" side of the obtuse triangle), and if you still require that the rectangle lies within the triangle, then the area of the rectangle must be strictly smaller than half the triangle area.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey How do you derive the $\frac{1}{2}h^2$? In particular, if you were rotate the rectangle in your picture by a very small angle (and make it appropriately smaller), then its area would be close to 42, which is larger than 32.

Comment: @dtldarek Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an elegant approach provided by Dr.Shailesh A Shirali.[image]

- BC = a, CA = b, AB = c
- PQRS: rectangle with PS ∥ BCand PQ ⊥ BC
- Triangle APS is similar to Triangle ABC
- Let AP/AB = t; then AS/AC = t and PS/BC = t
- Dimensions of Triangle APS: ta,tb, tc
- AD is an altitude of Triangle ABC
- AD = h
- Altitude of Triangle APS: th    (by similarity)
- PQ = h−th = (1−t)h

Following the train of reasoning as shown below figure, we see that:

Area of triangle ABC = (1/2)ah,

Area of rectangle PQRS = t(1−t)ah,

Here 0 <= t <= 1. The maximum value attained by t(1−t) for 0 <= t <= 1 is 1/4 ,

attained when t = 1/2 .

Hence the maximum possible area of PQRS is (1/4)ah, which is half the area of the triangle.